# How to pass variable inside Laravel Schema builder

Tags: php, variables, laravel-4

I could not make the following **Laravel** code working. I'm trying the following code. Here is the table columns array:

```
$cols = array(
   'inc' => array('id'),
   'str' => array(
              'name',
              'email',
              'password'
            ),
   ...
);
```

Here is the function:

```
private function addCols($tableName, $cols){
  foreach ($cols as $k => $type) {
   foreach ($cols[$k] as $col) {
    if(!Schema::hasColumn($tableName, $col)){
        Schema::table($tableName, function($table)
        {
          // Problem here $k and $col are `Undefined`

        }
        // Outside here $k and $col have values like `str`, `name`
    }
   }
  }
}
```

I'm not that good with PHP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `use` keyword is what you're looking for. It helps anonymous functions "inherit" existing variables that would otherwise be outside their scope:

```
    Schema::table($tableName, function($table) use ($k, $col)
    {
      // $k and $col are now defined
    }
```

Here's the doc:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-186

Comment: Thanks, this is it. Didn't know that. Again thanks for comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use it

```
public function addColumnTable($table_name,$field_name,$field_type){
    Schema::table($table_name, function (Blueprint $table) use($field_name,$field_type) {
        $table->{$field_type}($field_name);
    });
}
```